# Are two closed curves similar to each other if they have the same tangential vectors at the same position $\xi \in [0, 2\pi)$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations

Given two closed curves $X,Y:[0,2\pi) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with $X(0)=X(2\pi)$ and $Y(0)=Y(2\pi)$, if their tangential vectors are the same, which means $\mathcal{T}(X)|_\xi=\nabla_\xi X(\xi)/|\nabla_\xi X(\xi)|=\nabla_\xi Y(\xi)/|\nabla_\xi Y(\xi)|=\mathcal{T}(Y)|_\xi$, can we have there exist $r>0$ such that $rX \cong Y$?

Moreover, let $L_X$ and $L_Y$ be the length of $X$ and $Y$ respectively, can we have an estimate
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} (|\nabla_\xi X|-|\nabla_\xi Y|)^2 \mathrm{d} \xi \leq C(\int_0^{2\pi} |\mathcal{T}(X)-\mathcal{T}(Y)|^2 \mathrm{d} \xi, |L_X-L_Y|)?
$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your first question is no. Consider a rectangle. Smooth its corners, i.e., find a smooth embedded curve $\gamma\colon S^1\to\mathbb R^2$ which parametrises the edges of the rectangle when restricted to the subsets $U_k=\{e^{2\pi i (\phi+\frac{k}{4})}\mid \phi\in (\epsilon,\tfrac{1}{4}-\epsilon)\},$ $k=0,1,2,3.$ You can easily rescale the side-lengths of two opposite edges
(to be specific on $U_0$ and $U_2$)
by using a partition of unity, without changing the curve elsewhere. The new curve is in general not similar to the original one.